# Remove trailing special characters from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a regex to clean some data before I insert the items into the database. I haven't been able to solve the issue of removing trailing special characters at the end of my strings.

How do I write this regex to **only** remove trailing special characters?

```
import re

strings = ['string01_','str_ing02_^','string03_@_', 'string04_1', 'string05_a_']

for item in strings:
  clean_this = (re.sub(r'([_+!@#$?^])', '', item))
  print (clean_this)

outputs this:
string01 # correct
string02 # incorrect because it remove _ in the string
string03 # correct
string041 # incorrect because it remove _ in the string
string05a # incorrect because it remove _ in the string and not just the trailing _
```

Comment: Try `[_+!@#$?^]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could repeat the character class 1+ times or else only 1 special character would be replaced. Then assert the end of the string `$`. Note that you don't need the capturing group around the character class:

```
[_+!@#$?^]+$
```

For example:

```
import re
strings = ['string01_','str_ing02_^','string03_@_', 'string04_1', 'string05_a_']

for item in strings:
  clean_this = (re.sub(r'[_+!@#$?^]+$', '', item))
  print (clean_this)
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tNxKUY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jA69KT)

If you also want to remove whitespace characters at the end you could add `\s` to the character class:

```
[_+!@#$?^\s]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcGCsd/1)

Comment: For some reason, certain strings aren't being removed, such as 05_+_

Comment: my current regex is this: (re.sub(r'[!@#$%^&*<>?_\s]+$', '', item))

Comment: It seems to work https://ideone.com/qfhM1I  Can you share the code where you pull the values from the list?

Comment: It seems that the key was changing str(item_name).strip().lower() to repr(item_name).strip().lower() in the section of code that created the list containing the data.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the special purpose `rstrip` method of strings

```
[s.rstrip('_+!@#$?^') for s in strings]
# ['string01', 'str_ing02', 'string03', 'string04_1', 'string05_a']
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this method, because I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

You need an end-of-word anchor `$`

```
 clean_this = (re.sub(r'[_+!@#$?^]+$', '', item))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ok4pl4/1)

Comment: This works, but for some odd reason in my production data items that end with _ are not always removed.

Comment: Could you show examples of data that cause those issues?

Comment: some of the production data strings not being cleaned at the end:  on_+_  ,   05____ ,  50__j_

Comment: Are you sure there is no trailing whitespace?

Comment: It seems that the key was changing str(item_name).strip().lower() to repr(item_name).strip().lower() in the section of code that created the list containing the data.